How to get table schema in flutter sqflite
I know how to get sqlite table names in flutter sqflite from this link . However, I want to know is it possible to get entire table schema like all column names, primary key(s), foreign key(s) etc. in flutter using sqflite package.
I have tried using sqlite_master, but it only returning table names, not entire table schema.

See the sqlite_schema table as shown in https://www.sqlite.org/schematab.html
